# Pointer passing to function header

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have another problem regarding pointers.

I have a function with the following header:

```
 addActor (NxuPhysicsCollection &c, NxActor &a, const char *userProperties=0, const char *actorId=0)
```

And I am trying to use it like this:

```
 NXU::NxuPhysicsCollection* collection = new NXU::NxuPhysicsCollection();
 NxActor* actor = *actors++;
 NXU::addActor(collection, actor, NULL, NULL);
```

But I get the following error:

> A reference of type "NXU::NxuPhysicsCollection&" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialised with   a value of type "NXU::NxuPhysicsCollection*"  (this is for the collection parameter, same error appears for actor as well)

How am I supposed to pass the collection and actor parameters to the function in order to work properly?

I tried this:

```
 NXU::addActor(&collection, &actor, NULL, NULL);
```

But that doesn''t work either, it gives me the error:

```
 "Initial value of reference to non-const must be a lvalue."
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: If I use it like this:

```
NXU::addActor((NXU::NxuPhysicsCollection&)collection, (NxActor&)actor, NULL, NULL);
```

It does not give me errors anymore. Is this correct?

I must mention that NXU and NX namespaces are closed source and I cannot modify the way they are implemented

Comment: `I tried this: NXU::addActor(&collection, &actor, NULL, NULL);` How did you define `collection` and `actor` in this case?

Comment: I tried that too but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the formal arguments of your member function for `c` and `a` are *references*, while  `collection` and `actor` are *pointers*, you need to dereference pointers to make them compatible with references:

```
// No need to pass NULLs for the defaulted parameters, so
// the trailing NULL, NULL are removed.
NXU::addActor(*collection, *actor);
```

Alternatively, you can change the signature of the constructor to accept pointers instead of references:

```
addActor (NxuPhysicsCollection *c, NxActor *a, const char *userProperties=0, const char *actorId=0)
//                             ^           ^
//                             |           |
//                             Here and Here
```

Comment: Thank you, both you and Moo-Juice gave me the correct answer. I can't modify anything about the code since I don't have access to it.

Answer (score 3):

Both the `c` and `a` parameters are *references*.

Pass them as:

```
NXU::addActor(*collection, *actor, NULL, NULL);
```

This act is called pointer-dereference.

Answer (score 0):

```
NXU::addActor(*collection, *actor, NULL, NULL);
```

because

```
 addActor (NxuPhysicsCollection &c, NxActor &a, const char *userProperties=0, const char *actorId=0)
```

receives `collection` and `actor` *by reference*, not by pointer